# Cannot verify contracts with libraries on Etherscan

Tags: solidity, etherscan

Since the last week I have not been able to verify contracts on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/) if they use libraries. I was able to do this before. Apparently something has changed in Etherscan, Solidity compiler, or related that makes it not to picked up libraries I have linked in.

The contracts without libraries are fine.

What could such change to be? Any workaround (use specific Solidity version, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue on EtherScan service.

EtherScan resolved this issue yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

If you're submitting source code to EtherScan to verify the bytecode of a contract, if your code includes an `include` command, remove that line and replace it with the contents of the file to be included, so all the contract definitions (libraries, other contract interfaces or full contracts) are all in one file. Submitting that as the source should be accepted.

Take for example, the [Ethereum Alarm Clock source code](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6c8f2a135f6ed072de4503bd7c4999a1a17f824b#code). Note that that contract (`Scheduler`) in the Solidity source code uses `library GroveLib`. The Solidity source listed for the contract lists the definition of that library contract, and down lower, it also needs to indicate that the `GroveLib` contract it's using is at `0x7c1eb207c07e7ab13cf245585bd03d0fa478d034`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is not an answer I am looking for. I know how EtherScan works. However, it does not work anymore. I am asking why it is not working anymore.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Oh, I see, not just an include, but a Library specifically. I edited my answer to show an example of that. When submitting the code, there are form fields at the bottom of the page to input the locations of Library contracts used by the contract, which need to match the deployed code in order to verify.