# Verifying contracts with libraries

Tags: solidity, library, contract-verification

I have a problem very similar to this [Cannot verify contracts with libraries on Etherscan](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17341/cannot-verify-contracts-with-libraries-on-etherscan)

Simple code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16; //optimization enabled

library C {
function a() returns (address) {
    return address(this);
}}

contract A {
function a() constant returns (address) {
    return C.a();
}}
```

The library confirmed fine
https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x704aa2bfa624367854b98cb4167837384ba36417#code
But the contract referencing the library doesn't verify
https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xf2b6ec284e597aa52adb33ddefa39603cc0fb083

Including the library as

Library_1 Name: C

Library Contract Address: 0x704aa2bfa624367854b98cb4167837384ba36417

The verification bytecode output looks like this

> 6060604052341561000f57600080fd5b5b6101298061001f6000396000f300606060405263ffffffff7c01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000350416630dbe671f8114603c575b600080fd5b3415604657600080fd5b604c6075565b60405173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff909116815260200160405180910390f35b600073__:C____________________________________630dbe671f6000604051602001526040518163ffffffff167c010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002815260040160206040518083038186803b151560de57600080fd5b6102c65a03f4151560ee57600080fd5b50505060405180519150505b905600a165627a7a723058209f5ef34399bb3ea506b876feebc5f333e41860061c53be57c401685375bfab310029

Which obviously does not match :C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Library verification to work you have to use version 2.0 of Verify Contract Code (currently in Beta)

i.e. make sure the verification URL starts with https://etherscan.io/verifyContract2?a=